# How can I rewrite my URL in asp.net from QueryString to folder based URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, url-rewriting

I am doing project in ASP.Net, and i have used QueryString for dynamic profiles based on it.

```
*Resume.aspx?ID=UxppUvJJ===QM*
```

On the bases of this id, profiles are made at runtime, i want it like. If the user is atif,
it should be Resume.aspx/atif/ should go to the same url, if atif id is UxppUvJJ===QM
then on the bases of usernames, it should be moved according to ids.

Similarly if we do `Resume.aspx/atif/ar`
It should open arabic version, and if i do `Resume.aspx/atif/` it should open english version.
`Resume.aspx/atif/ar/SomePage.aspx` should be in arabic too.
I have also two resource files, one for arabic and one for english.

How can i do it in IIS and code?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of URLRewrite to achieve this kind of function...

Check this on msdn : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx